# 20rs 20 Animals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Suppose, you want to buy 20 animals and you have only 20rs ( rs = Indian currency ).
Cost of animals:-

---

1. 1 Buffalo = 5rs
2. 2 Cows = 1rs
3. 4 Goats = 1rs

---

So, the question is how many buffaloes, goats and cows will you buy to have 20 animals total in 20rs? I don't want to solve it with hit and trial method. I want the general solution for this type of questions.

I have $x + y + z = 20 , 5x + 0.5y + 0.25z = 20$

Comment: Can you write down 2 equations, one for the total cost of 20rs and one for the number 20 of animals?

Comment: These can be written with integer coefficients $x+y+z=20, 20x+y+2z=80$. This is a pair of simultaneous linear Diophantine equations (equations which must have integer solutions).  You can see an example solution process here https://brilliant.org/wiki/system-of-linear-diophantine-equations/

Comment: I didn't understand the example of Diophantine equation in 3 variables with restrictions applied  that was in the article you give. Can you provide the solution for this question. It will make more sense to me.

Comment: @GODofGamerZ The $2^{\text{nd}}$ equation in your $1^{\text{st}}$ comment is wrong. It has already prompted Paul to make a mistake in his $2^{\text{nd}}$ comment. I think it is better if you delete your $1^{\text{st}}$ comment. After all, you have stated the correct equation in your problem statement.

Comment: @GODofGamerZ You need to read the section called $\bf{\text{Diophantine Systems with Restrictions}}$ of the article mentioned in Paul's $2^{\text{nd}}$ comment. If you follow the instruction given in that section to the last letter, you would get the correct answer, i.e., 3-Buffalos, 3-Cows, and 14- Goats.

Comment: @YNK It wasn't me who edited my question. Because I let the no. of goats = y. But since it's making you confuse, I'm going to delete my comment. But can you provide me the solution for this question. I'm in 12th standard. I solved this question by elimination method by letting z equals 1,2,3.. because maximum value of z here can be 4. But what if maximum value would be 100 then I can't apply this method so I want a generalized method but it seems undergraduate level question. It's not in my syllabus. But now, I'm curious to this. I will be grateful to you if you solve this question.

Comment: My solution is the same as the website solution. Take some time to understand the website solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have the equations $x + y + z = 20 , 20x + 2y + z = 80$.

Because you only have two equations (but three unknowns) you can find each variable in terms of one of the others. It is best to use the variable which looks to be most restricted by the conditions (in this case $x$.)

You can now eliminate one of the other variables. For example, subtracting one equation from the other gives $$19x+y=60.$$
You now know that $y=60-19x$. Substitute this in the first of your equations to obtain $z=18x-40$. You have now completed the stage of getting all variables in terms of one of the others.

Now use each equation to see what value(s) are possible for $x$.

$19x$ cannot be greater than $60$ and so $x<4$. Can you see what the other equation tells you about $x$?

Ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: But what if the value of all the variables is too large like 243,666,1000? What are we supposed to do then??

Comment: I mean after solving what if x<100, y<345, z<4797 any random but large number.

Comment: @GODofGamerZ: *"But what if the value of all the variables is too large ...?"* Let a computer do some brute-force searching for you. Number Theory might provide insights that whittle down the possibilities. Be that as it may ... You might be interested in [Archimedes' Cattle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27s_cattle_problem), a Diophantine puzzle posed in antiquity but only explicitly solved in 1965, using a computer, due to the size of the solutions. (The smallest has $206544$ digits!) So, be thankful if your problem's variables "only" go to $100$ and $345$ and $4797$. :)

Comment: There is no particular issue here with large numbers. As with many mathematical problems we have developed a method which will lead to a solution but if carrying out the calculations is too involved then we prefer to use computers. However, what is more difficult than large numbers is having a large number of equations such as those in the Cattle problem.